# How can I wrap net/http middleware inside custom function in Golang?

Tags: go, router

I'm trying to build an interface for Context and implement `ctx.Next()` for middleware. Middleware would look like this

```
func Test() http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(ctx http.Context) error {
        return ctx.Next()
    }
}
```

I tried following code, but it's not working.

```
func (c *Context) Next() error {
    // body limit middleware
    nextHandler := func(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
        return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        })
    }
        // NOT SURE how to add handler and execute nextHandler
    return nil
}
```

Please suggest how it would work inside `ctx.Next()` for `net/http` middleware.

Code for chi: https://github.com/sujit-baniya/framework/blob/chi/http/chi_context.go#L125
Context interface: https://github.com/sujit-baniya/framework/blob/chi/contracts/http/context.go#L10

Comment: What is your ````http.Context````?

Comment: Context is an interface. And I'm trying to support multiple routers: `chi - Not Working`, `gofiber - Working`, `gin - Working`.

Comment: You may refer to gin sample https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/blob/v1.8.1/context.go#L170, add one handlers and index to your chi context  @SujitBaniya